# Form checkbox not setting when checked

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I have a form which which holds this checkbox and a variable I would like to send:

```
<input type="checkbox" name"deleteimg" value="checked"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currentimage" value="<?php echo $row['event_img'];?>" />
```

then my php checks if there is a value sent and if the checkbox is checked, it will set the variable to blank. ("")

```
$deleteimg=$_POST['deleteimg'];
$image=$_POST['currentimage'];

if(isset($deleteimg))
{
     $image='';//delete the current image
}
```

However this is not working when the checkbox is checked on form submit, and doesnt work if it isnt checked either.

If the checkbox is checked I want it to set a variable to blank ie "" so its clear in the Database. If its not checked the variable will be what is set in the $image variable on request.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

im not a php expert, but try using

```
 $HTTP_POST_VARS["deleteimg"]
```

to check the for the value.

Comment: Just seen my mistake. I hadn't put name="" I had put name""

Answer (score 0):

Rather than set $deleteim to the post variable, check its set first, as if you dont check it you get no value, if its checked you should get "checked" .. As I believe without testing, that by setting the $deleteimg variable it will always confirm its set.